applystatementsettings(ps) in jdbctemplate class taking lot of time in spring boot
we are migrating an application from struts to spring boot,
java 17,
DB is MSSQL.
IN one particular functionality we are reading values from an excel and updating a table.
its an update statement
,total columns in the table are around 36.
but we are updating only 4 columns in the table.
For 800 rows its taking 1min and 30 secs on average.
same operation in legacy struts application takes only milliseconds to finish - average 600 milliseconds.
so indexing is not the issue.
Time taken to Load excel file is negligible.
MSSQL driver is 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:6.1.0.jre7'
tried using below 2 drivers as well
 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:12.8.1.jre11'
 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:11.2.3.jre17'

in spring boot
tried with jdbctemplate batchupdate() and with normal prepared statement.executeBatch too.
but no change in performance.
tried using below properties
 - spring.jdbc.getParameterType.ignore=true
 - spring.jdbc.template.fetch-size=500
 - using @Transactional annotation on my method also
 - @EnableTransactionManagement has been set on the main class.
 - tried using RewriteBatchedStatements=true in db url.

total columns in the table are around 36.
below is the query
**UPDATE 006_PARTVHE_PRCC SET 006_UNCLAIMABLE_F=?,  006_REMARKS_X=?
, 006_LAST_UPDT_USER_C=?,006_LAST_UPDT_S=?, WHERE 006_INVOICE_R=?
 AND 006_PARTVHE_R=? AND 006_INVOCE_S=? AND 006_PRODUCT_TYPE_C=?
 AND 011_CLAIM_R IS NULL** 

Most of the time taken is after calling the
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate method.
did some debugging and found the maximum amount is spent inside
applyStatementSettings(ps) call inside JdbcTemplate class
Any idea where we would need to tweak to improve the performance.
thank you
